# My gnome-panel is misssing

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gnome-panel

In Ubuntu classic, Ubuntu classic (no effects) and safe mode the interface Panel is  missing in Natty 11.04, but it is normal in Unity 3D. How do I solve this problem?

> [image: safe mode Interface]
>   Screen-shot of the problem.

Comment: Which panel are you referring to? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: can you run a pkill gnome-panel from there, and see if it pops back out?

Comment: @hansioux I tried,but dosn't work

Comment: There should be a top and a bottom panel in classic try   "metacity --replace"

Answer (score 2):

In classic, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the run dialog. Then type `gnome-panel`.

If that doesn't work, try typing `gnome-panel` into a terminal. Then update your question with the error message(s) displayed.

Comment: thx a lot! I have solved this problem...

Comment: @Bakhtiyar: If my answer was what helped you solve the problem, please accept it so that other people can benefit. If there was some other solution, please write it up in your own answer and accept that.